# CakePHP 2.0 showing blank in admin, front works fine

Tags: cakephp, routes, admin

I made website on localhost with CakePHP 2.0 and its working fine. But after upload to server, front-end works fine, but back-end after login redirects and is showing blank.

- Debug set 2
- Cache cleaned

What can be wrong?
My Routes.php looks:

```
Router::connect("/" . URL_ADMIN , array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect("/admin/:controller", array('action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect("/admin/:controller/:action/*", array('prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
```

Comment: Look at tmp/logs and apache logs for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Include the file in your bootstap.php where all the constants are declared. If you are working on Admin section then it is a best approach to use "[Auth Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)". As you used `'admin' => true` option is primarily used for Admin related pages while Auth component has been integrated. Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: Hi Arun, Same problem I have, added admin=>true but still seeing blank page of admin on server only..